# made up of "development" or "developments"?

Tags: plural-forms, countability

> Much of the outer portion of this area is made up of low-rise residential development.

I think here "development" is used to describe ***a group of new buildings that have all been planned and built together on the same piece of land***. According to the dictionary, it is a countable noun when it is used as the meaning. So Should the "development" in the sentence be corrected as "developments". Why? Why not? Thanks！

Comment: Either is perfectly acceptable in this context - it carries no discernible distinction.

Comment: I think the author used this **[development](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/development)** in sense 1, "change, growth, or improvement over a period of time". I agree that if they wanted to mean "a group of buildings that have been built together on a piece of land", *developments" would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @FumbleFingers points out either is acceptable.
 I think the distinction is very slight but present and depends on the point the author was making.

If he had used "*developments*" that would have called attention to the fact that there are several different developments that make up the outer portion of the area.  I would have used *developments*, therefore, if my point was about the fact that these multiple independent developments ultimately cost more than if a single developer had been contracted to develop the whole area (for example).

In this case, though, I think the author was less interested in talking about them individually and just wanted to focus on them collectively. I think the author's point was in the low-rise nature of all the development in that area regardless of who had built which parts.  Thus *development* was used.