# Software development countable or not?

Tags: grammar, countable-nouns, countability

From this post ([made up of "development" or "developments"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13775/made-up-of-development-or-developments)) development can be singular or plural, which means it is countable, but how about `software development`?

Which might be correct?

`to see software development from a quality perspective`

Or

`to see a software development from a quality perspective`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you mean.

***A*** development is something which "develops", an emerging phenomenon, so "**a** software development" if it means anything means something happening in software; it doesn't necessarily have anything to do with the act or process of developing software.

I suspect that your ***a*** reflects a concern with a specific instance of software development rather than software development in general, and that you want

> to see the development of a specific program (*or* application *or* system *or whatever*) from a quality perspective.

---

Many speakers would be comfortable with *development of a specific software*, but I'm not one of them.

Comment: The only thing I don't like about this answer is "Many speakers would be comfortable with *development of a specific software*"... Because that's a scary thought!! Haha. +1 :)